# which facebook permission will be required?

Tags: android

I have an android application and want to add a functionality "Add Friend" . Suppose I have logged in using Facebook Credentials so on clicking "App Friend" I will get list of my Facebook friend who are also using same application using their Facebook credentials. I just want to know which facebook permissions will be required

Answer (score 0):

Here is facebook graph api references, and as I understood there is no ability to make friend request by graph api.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends

**Update**
Facebook invite dialog is deprecated, you can only get the list of user whose using the app

Comment: you mean to say it will give me list of such friends using said app but will not allow to invite

Comment: Yes you can't invite friends, Facebook deprecated this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the facebook developer doc. You need [user friend](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/)